# Why grammarly is not happy with "since a few minutes we are serving"?

Tags: grammar

I'm not a native speaker and I use Grammarly to correct my writings.

Today I tried to write:

> Since a few minutes we're serving the website from....

and Grammarly keeps asking me to change into:

> For a few minutes, we have been serving

Now my writing skills are not perfect, but to me, these two sentences have different meanings. The first one means that we are *still* serving the website from....
but the second one means that we have *stopped* doing it.

Am I correct or there is a usage of the word "for" that I don't know yet?

Comment: _Since_ requires a start time, not a duration. You could get away with 'Since a few minutes ago...' See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/proper-usage-of-since-and-from-with-regard-to-duration-of-time)

Comment: Or "For the last few minutes..." which indicates it's still current.

Comment: I do see this usage of "since" in text written by non-native speakers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["since ages" or "for ages"? ('since' with a time period)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151192/since-ages-or-for-ages-since-with-a-time-period)

Comment: Didn't you ever study *since* and *for* in your English classes? You might want to review those.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with "for", but with your usage of "since". As @KateBunting mentioned in her comment "since" requires a point in time, not a duration. Probably your native language is German because there "seit" can be used both ways, with a duration and a point in time and German dictionaries often declare "since" to be the tranlation of "seit" - which it is, but only in certain cases:

> Seit 3 Uhr 45 ...
> Seit einigen Minuten ....

These two phrases translated to English would be:

> *Since* a quarter to 4 ...
> *For* a few moments ...

A viable phrasing for your purpose would be:

> For a few minutes, we have been serving the website from ...

or ("since", with a point in time):

> Since a few minutes ago, we serve the website from ...

Comment: awesome response, thanks.
I do indeed speak German and Italian. In both languages, the same word can be used with a duration and with a point in time.

Comment: The  use of the present perfect (*For a few minutes it has worked*)  does not entail the meaning that it has stopped working.  *For a few minutes it has worked; let's hope that it continues to work until the replacement part arrives.*

Comment: Nicely written, and you're right about *since* and *for*. However, you're wrong on both counts regarding the use of the present perfect versus present perfect continuous.  Both of them are used to describe actions that have now ceased and both of them are used for actions that are ongoing. Also the concern is between using the present continuous and the present perfect continuous. The OP has the right concern here. Ping me if you edit your post and I'll come back and upvote you.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: As an aside, the way I answered is actually what I learned in school, where they "teach the english language a well-educated inhabitant of southern Britain (e.g. Cornwall) speaks". I guess the teaching of English here is not better than the teaching of German elsewhere: fraught with "rules" no native speaker has ever heard of.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: Btw., this site: https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/how-do-we-use-verbs-to-talk-about-continuing-actions-versus-completed-actions-or-states seems to concur with what I said, or have I misunderstood it completely?

Comment: @bakunin That's what you get if you try to look up grammar info in a dictionary! ;) For example, they describe *I have lived here for 4 years* as a completed action. Is it completed? Is it an action? Probably not! That whole page is a complete car crash. It gets worse and worse. Avoid like the plague.